# WebRTC's add track produces garbled sound in iOS swift Application

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, audio-streaming, peer

I am working on an iOS app in swift that allows live chat and call functionality. I am new to WebRTC. I am trying to add multiple call functionality using WebRTC. I got success in single P2P call.

Now, I am trying to merge two P2P connections by merging their audios. I am also creating and sending a new offer to both the connections. But the resulted audio is very poor.

Here are the steps that I am following:

1. A => B Call successful ==> Result: audio clear no problem on both
   the ends
2. A => C Call successful ==> Result: audio clear no problem on both
   the ends
3. When A => C connection is set up, I am merging both the connections
   with below code:

   ```
   for audioTrackAB in mediaStreamAB.audioTracks {
        connectionAC.add(audioTrackAB, streamIds: [mediaStreamAB.streamId])//Add audio track to the connectionAC
   }
   ```
4. Creating and sending renegotiation offer to C.
5. Again Step 3-4 for A => B connections.

When the other peers B/C receives renegotiation offer. There is code that will accept and answer the same.

Here is the link I got reference from.

https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/perfect-negotiation-in-webrtc/

The issue with this solution is after successfully merging the audio, B => C audio is very garbled.

Any help or suggestions will be helpful.